# mocking two function with jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing

I have two functions which one of them is called inside another function. and I am using this function in my component. However, I am not able to write a test for it.

```
export const componentToHex = (c) => {
  var hex = c.toString(16);
  return hex.length === 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
};

export const rgbToHex = (r, g, b) => {
  return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
};
```

As you can see I am calling componentToHex function in rgbToHex function. I have written tests but I am still not If I am writing them correctly.

this is what I am trying so far

```
import * as util from "./utils";  <---- importing the module

test("using jest fn", () => {
  const mocked = jest.fn();
  util.componentToHex = mocked;
  util.rgbToHex(255, 222, 255);
  expect(mocked).toBeCalledTimes(1);
});

test("using spy", () => {
  jest.spyOn("./utils", "rgbToHex");
  rgbToHex(255, 137, 255);
  expect(utils.rgbToHex).toHaveBeenCalledWith("#eaeaea");
});
```

Could you please help me figure this out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could test these two function. I do not know that it is completely correct or not. But so far this is working for me.

**this is the file that I am testing**

```
function componentToHex(c) {
  let hex = c.toString(16);
  return hex.length === 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
  return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}

const exportFunctions = {
  componentToHex,
  rgbToHex,
};

export default exportFunctions;
```

```
import utils from "./utils";

test("should return color with hex", () => {
  utils.componentToHex = jest.fn().mockReturnValue();
  const result = utils.rgbToHex("QJ", "Li", "ff");
  expect(result).toBe("#QJLiff");
});
```